# $f$ is bounded on $\sigma$ and holomorphic on $\sigma\setminus \{a\}$, where $a$ lies in $\sigma$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is a bounded function on $\sigma$ and $f$ is holomorphic on $\sigma\setminus \{a\}$, where $a$ lies in $\sigma$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic.

Can you provide a hint to get started with? I tried defining $g(z) = (z-a)f(z)$ and then show its limit goes to 0 when z goes to a. But I can not get forward.

Comment: Can you precise what are $\sigma$ properties? Open?...

Comment: $\sigma$ just denotes the domain. It is not any specific set.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann's_theorem for your updated question.

Comment: This isn't true as stated.  Take any  function $g$, holomorphic on $\sigma$ and define $f(z)=g(z)$ if $z\neq a$, f(a) = 1+g(a)$.  You need to assume $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Since $f$ is given to be bounded on $\sigma,$ by Riemann's theorem on removable singularity, the desired result follows.